# Save to parse manually after data has been queried

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am using Parse pinInBackground feature to pin data (image, text, date, coordinates) in the background and that data is queried every time the app is opened.The app is used to log a photo and the location and coordinates.So every entry you make is queried and displays in a tableview (only the count of entries yet).
I want to be able to let the user manually sink with Parse.com and not use the saveEventually feature. 
Meaning I want a button and when pressed the queried data must sink with Parse and the be in pinned. 
Here is how my data is pinned

```
@IBAction func submitButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    locationLogs["title"] = log.title
    locationLogs["description"] = log.descriptionOf
    println("log = \(log.title)")
    println("log = \(log.descriptionOf)")
    locationLogs.pinInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (success) {

        }else{
         println("error = \(error)")
        }}
 func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

    let location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location.coordinate
    let altitude: CLLocationDistance = manager.location.altitude

    println("new long= \(location.longitude)")
    println("new lat= \(location.latitude)")
    println("new altitude= \(altitude)")
    println("new timestamp = \(timestamp)")

    locationLogs["longitude"] = location.longitude
    locationLogs["latitude"] = location.latitude
    locationLogs["altitude"] = altitude
    locationLogs["timestamp"] = timestamp


}
```

And here I query it

```
var result : AnyObject?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let query = PFQuery(className:"LocationLogs")
    query.fromLocalDatastore()


    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock( { (NSArray results, NSError error) in
        if error == nil && results != nil {

           self.result = results
            println("count = \(self.result!.count)")
            self.loggedItemsTableView.reloadData()
        }else{
            println("ERRRROOOORRRR HORROOORRR= \(error)")
        }
    })

}
```

I have tried to use this command:

```
 result?.saveAllInBackground()
```

But this only gave back an error. 
Can someone please give me the correct code on how to do this or give me a link showing me how.

Comment: Please make it more clear what you are asking for. Are you asking someone to write the code for you? Do you have some code that does not work?

Comment: I edited the question, I want someone to give me the code on how to do it or just give me a link to a example on how to do this

Comment: what kind of error are you having? timeout? or invalid key fields from parse?

Comment: your `result` is of type `AnyObject` you should cast it first, no?

Comment: Yes I realized when I saw the error , but how do I set result equal to a PFObject that I can call saveInBackground on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a full code explanation on how I solved it:

```
//create an Array 
var tableData: NSArray = []

func queryAll() {
    let query = PFQuery(className:"LocationLogs")

    query.fromLocalDatastore()
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock( { (NSArray results, NSError error) in
        if error == nil && results != nil {
            println("array = \(results)" )
            self.tableData = results!
            self.loggedItemsTableView.reloadData()
        }else{
            println("ERRRROOOORRRR HORROOORRR= \(error)")
        }
    })
}

 //Call save on the class and not the object 
 PFObject.saveAllInBackground(self.tableData as [AnyObject], block: { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (success) {


            //Remember to unpin the data if it will no longer be needed
            PFObject.unpinAllInBackground(self.tableData as [AnyObject])

            println("Pinned Data has successfully been saved")

        }else{
            println("error= \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this to safely cast/checked your object

```
    if let results = self.result { // this will verify if your self.result is a non-nil array of object 
        // if it has a value then it will be passed to results
        // you can now safely proceed on saving your objects
        PFObject.saveAllInBackground(results, block: { (succeeded, error) -> Void in
            // additional code

            if succeeded {
                // alert, remove hud ......
            }else{
                if let reqError = error {
                    println(reqError.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: When will results be equal to result ?? You are just creating an empty let

Comment: self.result as? PFObject will be equal to nil

Answer (score 1):

```
struct log {
// this is dummy datastructure that imitate some part of your code ... you dont need it
var title = ""
var descriptionOf = ""
}

struct LocationInfo{

var title:String!
var description:String!
var location:PFGeoPoint!
var timestamp:NSDate!
var username:String

}

var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
 var arrayOfLocations = [LocationInfo]()

func submitButton(sender: AnyObject) {
var logData = log()

var point = OneLocation(locationManager)
let username = PFUser.currentUser()?.username
var locationLogs = PFObject(className: "")
locationLogs["title"] = logData.title
locationLogs["description"] = logData.descriptionOf
locationLogs["Location"] = point
locationLogs["username"] = username
locationLogs["TimeStamp"] = locationManager.location.timestamp
locationLogs.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success:Bool, error:NSError?) -> Void in
    if error == nil
    {
      println("data was save")
    }
}

}

 func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation (manager.location, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error)->Void in

    var UserCurrentLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location.coordinate
    // println("User's parking Location : \(UserCurrentLocation.latitude) \(UserCurrentLocation.longitude)")

    if (error != nil) {
        println("Error")
        return
    }
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

})
}

func OneLocation(Manager:CLLocationManager)->PFGeoPoint{
    var latitude = Manager.location.coordinate.latitude
    var longitude = Manager.location.coordinate.longitude
    var point  = PFGeoPoint(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    return point

  }

func QueryFromParse(){
var query = PFQuery(className: "")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
    if error == nil
    {
        if let new_objects = objects as? [PFObject]
        {
            for SingleObject in new_objects
            {
                // with this single object you could get the description, title , username,etc
                var location = SingleObject["Location"] as! PFGeoPoint
                var username = SingleObject["username"] as! String
                var title = SingleObject["title"] as! String
                var time = SingleObject["TimeStamp"] as! NSDate
                var description = SingleObject["description"] as! String

                var singleLocationInfo = LocationInfo(title: title, description: description, location: location, timestamp: time, username: username)
                arrayOfLocations.append(singleLocationInfo)
                // reload data for the tableview

            }

        }

    }
    else
    {
      println("error")
    }
  }
```

}

> Therefore you have an arrayoflocations that can be used to populate data in your tableView 
>   Struct log is a dummy datastructure 
>   And also I don't know if that was what you wanted ... but you should get the idea..
>   Hope that helps..

Comment: Remember to vote for the question BENQ has raised a valid question